# DDD Modeling - Generic and Specific

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, data-modeling

Suppose I am buying coffee. There are several types of coffee (medium roast, dark roast), but sometimes I want to make a reference to all types of coffee (like if I had a coffee "grouped"). Considering DDD concepts, coffee A1 is different from all types of coffee, so that's their identities and I need to reference both specific and generic Coffee Entity.

I thought I could map it like:

```
class Coffee{ 
  private CoffeeId id;
  @NotNull
  private Code code;
  private SubGroup subGroup; 
}
```

Imagine I have an entity PriceTable and sometimes I need to have values to all types of coffee and sometimes by some specific types. This means that in some use cases I need to refer just medium roast and in another cases I need to refer to all kind of coffees. For the last case, I suppose attribute "subGroup" could be "null".

Someone finds another way to transform these use cases into entities? I thought about a Strategy pattern but could not get the code to this

Comment: i don't really know about what you are asking ... I'm making an uneducated observation ...... it appears to be something similar to a relational database .... maybe, instead of specifying `ca1`, use something like `c.a1` .... note: the question may be clearer if you used apples as an example A1, A2, A3 ... red, green, yellow ... sour, sweet .....`sour.green.A1`

Comment: I've tried to give some real examples. Is it clearer to you?

Comment: And yes, it's a relational database

Answer (score 1):

> This means that in some use cases I need to refer just medium roast and in >another cases I need to refer to all kind of coffees.

Whenever you want to match data/behaviors to a subset of elements that usually screams [specifications](https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) or predicates.

The coffees would have some attributes, like `type`, `roast`, etc. for instance which then can be leveraged by the specifications/predicates for matching.

Here's a very simple example in JavaScript...

```js
const coffees = [
  { id: 1, type: 'espresso', roast: 'medium' },
  { id: 2, type: 'latte', roast: 'dark' },
  { id: 3, type: 'cappuccino', roast: 'light' }
];

const prices = [
    [c => c.id === 1, 6],
    [c => c.type === 'latte', 5],
    [c => true, 3]
];

const discounts = [
    [c => c.roast === 'light' || c.roast === 'medium', 0.15],
    [c => true, 0]
];


function priceOf(coffee) {
  const price = prices.find(([predicate, price]) => predicate(coffee))[1];
  return price - (price * discountFor(coffee));
}

function discountFor(coffee) {
  return discounts.find(([predicate, discount]) => predicate(coffee))[1];
}

console.log(priceOf(coffees[0]));
console.log(priceOf(coffees[1]));
console.log(priceOf(coffees[2]));
```

Obviously that's a very contrived example, but you should get the idea. With more complex specifications you could determine which are more generalized or specific and apply matching order rules based on that (e.g. more specific rule wins).

Honestly I'm not entirely sure I understood your problem completely, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yeah it's almost there. I've achieved this approach too, but suppose I have to store an ID representing all types of coffee. How would you do this with specifications?

Comment: Well, I thought the challenge was to price coffees without have a 1-1 price relationship. If you have a price attached to each coffee then the problem is trivial no? I must not understand your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without more precisions on the specific use case.

First of all, if in an object you need to put null, it's sure that you had a design problem.

To avoid this, we could imagine this solution :

```
class Coffee { 
  private CoffeeId id;
  private Code code;
}

class CoffeeWithSubGroup { 
  private Coffee coffee;
  private SubGroup subgroup;
}
```

Your Domain of buying coffee need more vocabulary and design.

For exemple, if your want to apply Discount on SubGroup, you can have a class SubGroupDiscount and by the same way, GeneralDiscount to apply a Discount on a Beverage (a possible interface for Coffee ?)

In that case, it's easier to retrieve all Coffee objects from a Repository and apply all your Discounts.

In general, when you try to apply DDD, start by Strategic pattern (Ubiquitous Language, Bounded Context and Context Map) then I think implementation will be easier.